# Batch File to Log REG complex value (data)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, window

my problems is that i want to set a variable with a registry value 
but the data value itself to complicated to use tokens.
i have tried to use:

```
for /F "tokens=3* delims=" %%g IN 
    ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" 
    /v Path  ^| findstr /i Path') do set OLD_SYSTEM_PATH=%%g
```

But the output is the full REG value including the "`Path`" and "`Type`"

Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```dos
for /F "tokens=2*" %%g IN ('
    reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path 
    ^| findstr /i /l "Path"
') do set "OLD_SYSTEM_PATH=%%h"
```

Remove the `delims` clause to use the spaces and tabs as delimiters, request the second input token (the type) to the indicated `for` replaceable paramenter (`%%g`), and the rest of the line to the next `for` replaceable parameter (`%%h`)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off    
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=1 delims= " %%a IN ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path') do (
set OLD_SYSTEM_PATH=%%a 
)
 echo %old_system_path%
```